# Getting error TS2339: Property 'tabs' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

On trying to enter the below script in angular getting error TS2339: Property 'tabs' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

where #mainTabs is the tab section id

```
$(function() {
      $( "#mainTabs" ).tabs();
  });
```

Comment: Can you include your #mainTabs element's  html code?

Comment: Which `@types` file are you using? Should be `@types/jqueryui` I believe

Comment: yes its @types/jqueryui